# On cyclic extensions.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I would really appreciate it if you help me with the following problem:

Suppose K is algebraically closed, f is an automorphism of K of infinite order, and k is the elements of K fixed by f.
Show that any finite extension of k is cyclic.

Apparently, it a a generalization of a similar problem due to Artin, in which K is the Rationals and f is an automorphism of algebraic closure of Q and k the fixed field.

Comment: I am trying different kinds,,,but have no idea why the automorphism f should be of infinite order!?!

Comment: Do you know about the Galois correspondence for algebraic (possibly infinite degree) field extensions?  This follows pretty easily from that.